# Canonical clarification of when and how to go to HR?

Tags: discussion

After much back and forth, I think that "HR IS NOT YOUR FRIEND", doesn't really convey the message that is intended.

It's usually in response to someone who is unaware of what HR is, what it isn't, and when going to HR is warranted, and when it would be a bad idea.

HR questions come up frequently, and there are many younger workers who are unaware of when and how to approach HR.

Comment: "When and how should I approach HR?" or some variation of that like "What role does HR have?" seems like a great question to me. I know the "HR is not your friend" thing has gained some traction here but I'm personally not a fan as I find it lacks nuance and introduces a concept that doesn't belong in a professional context (friends <> enemies). "HR works for your company not you" would say the same thing more effectively and is almost self-explanatory.

Comment: The advantage of a canonical post explaining in clear and ideally neutral terms what role HR does and doesn't have is that it gives you a target to link to when commenting "HR is not your friend!" without having to launch into an explanation in the comments. (IIRC there are 1 or 2 answers out there that can already be used for this where you or someone else explains the concept.)

Comment: @Lilienthal I know I am a primary offender here, and when I use it, it's usually in the context of wanting to scream "OMG, you are about to put your job in jeopardy".  But, yes, something that spells it out clearly would help

Comment: I second @Lilienthal first commend and alternate phrasings. This is indeed a recurrent theme here on TWP.

Comment: @Lilienthal - I'm having a hard time imagining a canonical of what HR does that isn't filled with an almost infinite set of variations. In my career, I worked at everything from tiny startups to megacorps. HR was different in most of them. Sometimes HR does x. Sometimes HR does y. Sometimes HR is outsourced. Sometimes HR is part time. Sometimes there is no HR. Etc, etc.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes, but there are some basics such as 1-They work for the company's interests. 2-going to them about a problem triggers an investigation 3-once they start an investigation it is out of your hands.  Then, there's what sort of information should be brought to them, and what shouldn't

Comment: But my mate Richard reckons HR is not your friend......

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I don't expect an exhaustive answer of every possible task HR can do but it's perfectly reasonable in my view to explain in broad stroke what falls under HR, what their usual roles are and as an example how it includes payroll at some firms but not all. Take the Wikipedia article on HR as an example: it covers the basics well within our typical post lengths.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter - "2-going to them about a problem triggers an investigation" sometimes, not always.

Comment: Do we have any canonical Questions/Answers for The Workplace? If so, where are they? Are they actually used?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I was wondering the same thing. I guess if someone asks the question 'When and how to go to HR', and then answers it, it would have the same affect? But I doubt they could cover everything except very general information which might not even apply some places. So whats the point?

Comment: @Kilisi - I've read here on Meta about creating canonical Questions/Answers for The Workplace. I could see it working for other forums. But I'm looking for examples where it has actually worked here in TWP. Maybe there are none?

Comment: In fact we could have a question (or more) that could ask what are the responsabilities or the various rôle among project/team leader, manager, HR, coworker and what are the expected professional interaction. We have huge number of question that stem from the fact that lot of people don't know that.

Comment: @Walfrat I would think that it varies enormously between industries, locales and maybe even companies and individuals, so it would just be a very general answer of limited use?

Comment: Are you aware of this post: [What does HR do for me?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/81773/what-does-hr-do-for-me)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Some regular questions should be able to serve as canonical posts, if it weren't for the fact that answerers (and voters, editors and people closing and reopening questions) generally focus heavily on the immediate problem of the asker instead of also trying to provide long-term value by making something a bit more general so it would also answer the question of those with a similar problem.

Comment: @BernhardBarker - so it sounds like you are saying that canonical questions/answers *could* work in ideal world, but that in reality they *don't*. Okay.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I'm saying on *this site specifically* canonical posts don't naturally come about (and people are generally not too interested in having them specifically created), whereas they do naturally come about on other Stack Exchange sites (like Stack Overflow, where people sometimes also specifically create them). This is not to say it happens as often as I think it should on those sites, but at least it does sometimes happen.

Comment: @BernhardBarker I find your logic in this matter to be impenetrable.

Comment: @BernhardBarker - okay, then if I understand what you are saying, I guess I agree. I can imagine them working on other sites, but I can't imagine them working here.

Comment: @BernhardBarker, it's OK to focus heavily on the immediate problem and address the specifics of an OP's situation. Can such answers apply to other situations? perhaps. But if someone has a similar question they can ask it-- as long as the dupe police don't shut it down or scare away the OP with harsh needless downvotes. It's really NOT feasible to give "canonical" answers to problems which are intrinsically subjective.

Comment: @teego1967 I'm not saying focusing heavily on the specifics of an OP's situation is objectively bad (and, either way, there's still a decent amount of room for that). We could argue about the pros and cons: you can answer an individual question in the best way possible to help the asker, which comes at the cost of not being particularly useful for people coming from Google (which, IIRC, is the majority of SE traffic). But really what it comes down to is what the intended goal of Stack Exchange / Workplace is, which is definitely more focused on long-term value than users here are.

Comment: @teego1967 Why do you think the functionality to close things as duplicates even exists, if it's not something we're ever supposed to use?

Comment: @teego1967 Actually I feel using the word "canonical" might be a bit counter-productive, as that occasionally leads to a discussion about semantics. What I mean when I say a "canonical question" is having a single question with answers that help as many people as possible based on how they're structured and phrased and having them address some common alternatives to the problem the asker is facing. This does not prevent anyone from posting their own answer with their own take on this (for the most part).

Comment: @BernhardBarker, sometimes questions really are duplicates. Often, however, they are not. There are some people on here (for example, gnat) who mark questions as "duplicate" for even the most trivial superficial similarity to an existing question. This is needlessly harsh and unwelcoming especially to new contributors. Having so-called "canonical" answers to certain questions would only encourage people to mark even more questions as dupes. I think that's counterproductive.

Comment: @teego1967 People being overeager to close things for any reason is not good, but whether it's okay to go too far in the opposite direction and be too hesitant to do so relates back to whether we should care at all about long-term value. There were [only 8 duplicate closures](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2021-01+duplicate%3Ayes) in the last month, out of 800+ questions. I don't think that rate is nearly high enough to worry about. I would rather advocate for educating some on how to correctly use duplicate votes instead of just getting everyone to use it less often.

Comment: @BernhardBarker I've never been a fan of the term because it seems to be a purely SO thing. The [definition](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291994/1103571) is decent enough though, the main purpose is a high quality set of answers to a recurring question that usually acts as a dupe target for common questions. To my knowledge we have at most a handful of questions that were created to fit these criteria while we have plenty that have grown to become a sort of reference answer here. The [linked question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/81773/25739) is arguably the latter.

Comment: @Lilienthal The overwhelming majority of questions I ever feel the need to use for duplicate closure, or just to link to, have answers littered with specifics about the question that are somewhere between not-at-all useful and requiring reading between the lines to apply it to one's own situation. The what-HR-does answers don't really explain which issues you should (not) go to HR with. [The asking-for-a-raise answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1025) addresses the specific raise OP wants to ask for and their certification. And those are the more reference-worthy, most are much worse

Answer (score 7):

Our base is too broad, what applies in some locales would be job threatening in others. Each question needs to be answered based on it's own situation.

Answer (score -5):

Eh, it seems pretty simple to me:

If you have a problem or complaint, go to your boss.
If your boss is the problem, go to HR.

There aren't really any exceptions to that rule for me.

Comment: It's never as cut and dry as that.

Comment: I thought of ten exceptions to that rule between reading the answer and writing this comment.

Comment: What a bizarre response. You have let the downvotes get to you.

Comment: I don't even remember what it was but I'm sure it was based and owned whoever I was responding to.

Comment: Any arguments against this rule? Some exceptions are not enough to think that this rule is wrong. +1 to this answer from me.

Comment: "I thought of ten exceptions" - fails to mention what any of them are. I can't think of a single exception myself.

Comment: General administrative issues are handled by HR for the most part. Speaking to HR would make sense if you're facing harassment or bullying from a fellow employee (there are certainly some well-publicised instances where HR tried to sweep those complaints under the rug, but generally they're who you should take those complaints to). I'm doubtful of the extent a typical manager would be able to help with that, especially if the other employee isn't their subordinate. If you speak to HR if your boss is "the problem", but they didn't do anything objectively wrong, then HR may not do much.

Comment: General administrative issues are handled by HR for the most part, correct, but you go to your boss first and tell them you have a general administrative issue, and then they tell you to go to HR. Common professional courtesy. Speaking to HR on bullying would absolutely make sense, but only after you've raised it with your boss first (unless your boss is the bully or is part of the problem). It's true that HR might not do much if you go to them about a problem with your boss, but that's hardly a reason not to approach them.